Keycloak Grant Acess page customization
I'm developing a theme for Keycloak, and I've already been able to customize the login page and the page to create a new user, but I still haven't managed to customize the "grant access" page.
Can you explain how I can do this?
I already have the layout created, but I haven't been able to apply it to Keycloak yet. I'm talking about the page in the image below:
Grant Access page
For this "grant access" page, I was just doing it the same way I did with the other pages, I created an .ftl and .css file. Supposedly the Login theme allows you to change the Grant access page.
